# Codeigniter Routing automatically

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I want to route multiple controllers.

I do have the following construct:

Controllers: `app_cart , cart , app_categories , categories , etc`

I want to route to the app_cart controller if the url is like this:

```
url.com/app/cart
```

and to cart when url is like this:

```
url.com/cart (thats what codeigniter does on his own!)
```

Any solutions? I dont want to route every single funtion and param! :/

EDIT:

I found a solution:

```
$route['app/(:any)'] = 'app_$1';
```

Hope this will help somebody! ;)

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html hope this link will help you

Comment: @ShaifulIslam I checked this already.... and I am not new to Codeigniter but i think i need some break :D sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

Apply this in your `application/config/routes.php`

For Controller: app_cart

```
$route['app/cart'] = "app_cart";
```

For Controller: app_categories

```
$route['app/categories'] = "app_categories";
```

**Note**: The above settings point your `index` function/method for your controllers because still you are not mention function/method name in the url

***If you want to point specific function/method for your controllers, then you should mention the name in URL. Below is a sample configuration***

For Controller: app_cart/view

```
$route['app/cart/view'] = "app_cart/view";
```

For Controller: app_categories/view

```
$route['app/categories/view'] = "app_categories/view";
```

**Note**: `view` is a function/method name for your controllers

Comment: thx for response but if i use this, i have to do this for every controller and function! Check out my EDIT, i already found a solution!

Comment: yes, that's good, In case if all your controllers are like that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
$route['app/(:any)'] = 'app_$1';
```